# How do I patch a ROM (game emulation) under Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, emulation, patch

I'm having problems patching gaming ROM files with a game patch (the English translation to the main game). I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (I presume that I can ask questions on Ask Ubuntu about using emulators<sup>1</sup>, like [RetroArch](https://www.retroarch.com/) and [Citra 3DS](https://citra-emu.org/)).

In Windows all I had to do was put the main file and the patch file in a new folder and the select the files, then use *Extract Here* with 7-Zip. With Ubuntu the files get extracted separately.

So how do I patch a ROM (game emulation) under Ubuntu?

<sub><sup>1</sup>An emulator is a hardware or software that permits programs written for one computer to be run on another computer. QEMU (Quick EMUlator) is an emulator that many Ubuntu users are familiar with.</sub>